# Asp in python in IIS 7 is giving HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error

Tags: python, iis-7, asp-classic

I am using Windows 7 and IIS 7 not as administrator but as a user. I have installed asp module and cgi module in IIS 7 in application development feature. My simple classic asp page is working which is :

```
<%response.write("Hello World")%>
```

My cgi in python is working which is :

```
print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print "Hello World!"
```

But when I am using python script inside asp page it is showing HTTP/1.1 500 server error
The code I am using is :

```
<%@Language=Python%>

<%
x="Hello"
response.write(x)
%>
```

I have searched the net for 4 days but didnt get any luck.
I enabled “Anonymous Authentication” in Authentication ,Unregistered and registered the pyscript.py for ASP, Provided python with IUSR and gave IUSR full control,Enabled “Enable-32 Bit Application” to True didnt worked.

Comment: is there any answers?Please post.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution to it.

The steps to be performed are

1. Register Python with ASP:

   - Open Command Prompt
   - Go to `{python_installation_dir}\Lib\site-packages\win32comext\axscript\client`
   - Run `python pyscript.py`
2. Enable 32-bit application for IIS7

   - Go to **IIS7**
   - Right click on your site's application pool
   - Select **Advanced Settings**
   - Under **General**, set **Enable 32-Bit Application** to **True**
3. Add **IIS_IUSRS**, **IUSR** or **USERS** to your virtual directory:

   - Right click on the directory
   - Click **Edit Permission**
   - Select the **Security** tab.
   - Give the account at least read permissions.