# Python POST Request Failing

Tags: javascript, python, post

I'm looking to do a POST request on this site:

http://web1.ncaa.org/stats/StatsSrv/careersearch

The form on the right has four dropdowns. When I run the code below, "School" stubbornly doesn't become selected. There's a hidden input that may be causing the problem, but I haven't been able to fix it. The javascript on the page doesn't seem to have an effect, but I could be wrong. Any help is appreciated:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://web1.ncaa.org/stats/StatsSrv/careersearch'
values = {'searchOrg' : '30123','academicYear' : '2011','searchSport' : 'MBA','searchDiv' : '1'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print the_page
```

Comment: How is it failing? Is it raising an error? Returning something you don't expect?

Comment: You should obey the site's robots.txt.

Comment: value="30123" is not showing up as selected, while the other values I listed are.

Comment: Try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133899/python-and-mechanize-login-script  I like the mechanize part. `b.select_form(nr=2)` is by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, you're missing a hidden field: `doWhat = 'teamSearch'` (for submitting the form on the right).

Using these request values works for me:

```
values = {'doWhat':'teamSearch', 'searchOrg' : '30123','academicYear' : '2011','searchSport' : 'MBA','searchDiv' : '1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used mechanize:

```
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

mech = mechanize.Browser() 
mech.set_handle_robots(False)
response = mech.open('http://web1.ncaa.org/stats/StatsSrv/careersearch')
mech.select_form(nr=2)
mech.form['searchOrg'] = ['30123']
mech.form['academicYear'] = ['2011']
mech.form['searchSport'] = ['MBA']
mech.form['searchDiv'] = ['1']
mech.submit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(mech.response().read())
```

I know in mechanize the site was asking for **searchOrg**, **academicYear**, **searchSport**, **searchDiv** in sequence/list form.  You should definitely be mindful of the robots.txt.