# Python - Requests/RoboBrowser - ASPX POST JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

I am porting a bash script that uses curl and POSTs the payloads in the code to the URL's and works. The basic issue is that, with robobrowser, I'm running into trouble posting using the page forms.

Stepping through the site:

- Login to /SubLogin.aspx
- Successful login redirects /OptionsSummary.aspx
- GET /FindMe.aspx with params
- POST /FindMe.aspx button "Phone Lists" (page should then load "Phone Lists" table with a item "Work")
- Selecting the "Work" item executes a POST to /PhoneLists.aspx (this should then load a table "Work" with list of users.

I have been able to successfully authenticate to the site and perform GETs with both RoboBrowser and Requests+bs4 however
I'm confused on POSTing back to the pages themselves.

Using RoboBrowser (liboncall.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

oc_mailbox = '123456'
oc_password_hashed = 'ABCDEFG'

base_uri = 'http://example.com'
auth_uri = oc_base_uri + '/SubLogin.aspx'
find_uri = oc_base_uri + '/FindMe.aspx'
phne_uri = oc_base_uri + '/PhoneLists.aspx'


p_auth_payload = {
        'SubLoginControl:javascriptTest': 'true',
        'SubLoginControl:mailbox': mailbox,
        'SubLoginControl:phoneNumber': '',
        'SubLoginControl:password': password_hashed,
        'SubLoginControl:btnLogOn': 'Logon',
        'SubLoginControl:webLanguage': 'en-US',
        'SubLoginControl:initialLanguage': 'en-US',
        'SubLoginControl:errorCallBackNumber': 'Entered telephone number contains non-dialable characters.',
        'SubLoginControl:cookieMailbox': 'mailbox',
        'SubLoginControl:cookieCallbackNumber': 'callbackNumber',
        'SubLoginControl:serverDomain': ''
        }

p_find_payload = {
        'FindMeControl:enableFindMe': 'on',
        'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:focusElement': '',
        'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:masterList:_ctl0:enabled': 'on',
        'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:masterList:_ctl0:itemGuid': '',
        'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidSelectedScheduleName': '',
        'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidbtnStatus': '',
        'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidScheduleXML': '',
        'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:tempScheduleXML': '',
        'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidSelectedScheduleGUID': '',
        'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidChangedScheduleList': '',
        'FindMeControl:btnPhoneLists': 'Phone Lists',
        'FindMeControl:enableFindMeHidden': '',
        'FindMeControl:applySet': 'false'
        }

p_phne_payload = {
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
        '__EVENTTARGET': 'PhoneListsControl$MasterDataControl$masterList$_ctl0$SelectButton',
        'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:focusElement': '',
        'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:masterList:_ctl0:itemGuid': '',
        'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:hidSelectedScheduleName': '',
        'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:hidbtnStatus': '',
        'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:hidScheduleXML': '',
        'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:tempScheduleXML': '',
        'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:hidSelectedScheduleGUID': '',
        'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:hidChangedScheduleList': '',
        'PhoneListsControl:applySet': 'false'
        }


def auth(mailbox, password):
    browser = RoboBrowser(history=False)
    browser.open(oc_auth_uri)

    signin = browser.get_form(id='aspnetForm')
    signin['SubLoginControl:mailbox'].value = mailbox
    signin['SubLoginControl:password'].value = password
    signin['SubLoginControl:javascriptTest'].value = 'true'
    signin['SubLoginControl:btnLogOn'].value = 'Logon'
    signin['SubLoginControl:webLanguage'].value = 'en-US'
    signin['SubLoginControl:initialLanguage'].value = 'en-US'
    signin['SubLoginControl:errorCallBackNumber'].value = 'Entered+telephone+number+contains+non-dialable+characters.'
    signin['SubLoginControl:cookieMailbox'].value = 'mailbox'
    signin['SubLoginControl:cookieCallbackNumber'].value = 'callbackNumber'
    signin['SubLoginControl:serverDomain'].value = ''

    browser.submit_form(signin)
    return browser
```

Login to site and show URL to verify we're in:

```
In [20]: from liboncall import *
In [21]: m = auth(oc_mailbox, oc_password_hashed)

In [22]: m.url
Out[22]: u'http://example.com/OptionsSummary.aspx'
```

Open "/FindMe.aspx":

```
In [24]: m.open(find_uri)

In [25]: m.url
Out[25]: u'http://example.com/FindMe.aspx'
```

Initially "/FindMe.aspx" will load a form and a button "Phone Lists", (`FindMeControl:btnPhoneLists`).

```
In [26]: m.select('title')
Out[26]: [<title>Find Me</title>]

In [27]: form_find_a = m.get_form(action="FindMe.aspx")

In [28]: for i in form_find_a.keys():
    print(i)
    ....:
    __VIEWSTATE
    __EVENTVALIDATION
    FindMeControl:enableFindMe
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:focusElement
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:masterList:_ctl0:enabled
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:masterList:_ctl0:itemGuid
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnAdd
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnDelete
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnRename
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnCancel
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnEnter
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnUpdate
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidSelectedScheduleName
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidbtnStatus
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidScheduleXML
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:tempScheduleXML
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidSelectedScheduleGUID
    FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidChangedScheduleList
    FindMeControl:btnApply
    FindMeControl:btnSchedules
    FindMeControl:btnPhoneLists
    FindMeControl:enableFindMeHidden
    FindMeControl:applySet
```

Remove un-needed form fields, fill out form and submit:

```
In [29]: find_remove = (
'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnAdd',
'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnDelete',
'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnRename',
'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnCancel',
'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnEnter',
'FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:btnUpdate',
'FindMeControl:btnApply',
'FindMeControl:btnSchedules')

In [30]: for i in find_remove:
        form_find_a.fields.pop(i)

In [31]: form_find_a['FindMeControl:enableFindMe'].value = 'on'
form_find_a['FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:focusElement'].value = ''
form_find_a['FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:masterList:_ctl0:enabled'].value = 'on'
form_find_a['FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:masterList:_ctl0:itemGuid'].value = ''
form_find_a['FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidSelectedScheduleName'].value = ''
form_find_a['FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidbtnStatus'].value = ''
form_find_a['FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidScheduleXML'].value = ''
form_find_a['FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:tempScheduleXML'].value = ''
form_find_a['FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidSelectedScheduleGUID'].value = ''
form_find_a['FindMeControl:MasterDataControl:hidChangedScheduleList'].value = ''
form_find_a['FindMeControl:btnPhoneLists'].value = 'Phone Lists'
form_find_a['FindMeControl:enableFindMeHidden'].value = ''
form_find_a['FindMeControl:applySet'].value = 'false'
Out [31]: ...

In [32]: m.submit_form(form_find_a)
```

Verifying that page has updated and has the list item "Work":

```
In [33]: m.parsed.find('title')
Out[33]: <title>Phone Lists</title>

In [34]: m.parsed.find('a', id='PhoneListsControl_MasterDataControl_masterList__ctl0_SelectButton')
Out[34]: <a class="linkButtonItem" href="javascript:__doPostBack('PhoneListsControl$MasterDataControl$masterList$_ctl0$SelectButton','')" id="PhoneListsControl_MasterDataControl_masterList__ctl0_SelectButton" onclick="javascript:onClick();">Work</a>
```

Get the "PhoneLists.aspx" form, remove un-needed fields, fill out and submit.

```
In [35]: form_find_b = m.get_form(action='PhoneLists.aspx')

In [36]: phne_remove = (
    'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:btnAdd',
    'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:btnDelete',
    'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:btnRename',
    'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:btnCancel',
    'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:btnEnter',
    'PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:btnUpdate',
    'PhoneListsControl:btnApply',
    'PhoneListsControl:btnBack')

In [37]: for i in phne_remove:
            form_find_b.fields.pop(i)

In [38]: form_find_b['PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:focusElement'].value = ''             
form_find_b['PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:hidChangedScheduleList'].value = ''
form_find_b['PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:hidScheduleXML'].value = ''
form_find_b['PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:hidSelectedScheduleGUID'].value = ''
form_find_b['PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:hidSelectedScheduleName'].value = ''
form_find_b['PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:hidbtnStatus'].value = ''
form_find_b['PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:masterList:_ctl0:itemGuid'].value = ''
form_find_b['PhoneListsControl:MasterDataControl:tempScheduleXML'].value = ''
form_find_b['PhoneListsControl:applySet'].value = 'false'

In [39]: m.submit_form(form_find_b)
```

Review the post to see if user list loaded. In this instance, it did not load
the user list.

```
In [40]: m.parsed.findAll('div', id='PhoneListsControl_phoneListMembersText')
Out[41]: [<div class="displayText" id="PhoneListsControl_phoneListMembersText"></div>]
```

*If* it was successfull the above would return:

```
<div id="PhoneListsControl_phoneListMembersText" class="displayText" style="top: 315px; left: 281px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Work&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

Along with the following items in a table, (`PhoneListsControl_phoneListDetail`):

```
<input name="PhoneListsControl:phoneListDetail:_ctl2:number" type="text" value="95551234567" maxlength="50" id="PhoneListsControl_phoneListDetail__ctl2_number" onkeyup="enableApplyButton('PhoneListsControl_')" style="width:140px;">
...
<input name="PhoneListsControl:phoneListDetail:_ctl3:number" type="text" value="95551236789" maxlength="50" id="PhoneListsControl_phoneListDetail__ctl2_number" onkeyup="enableApplyButton('PhoneListsControl_')" style="width:140px;">
...
```

At this venture I figured out that Robobrowser isn't including all the required
formdata for the post to "PhoneLists.aspx" to work as expected, (`'__EVENTTARGET':'PhoneListsControl$MasterDataControl$masterList$_ctl0$SelectButton'` and `__EVENTARGUMENT`). Setting the params and then doing `submit_form(form_find_b)` does not achieve desired results either. I wonder if the `add_field()` from `robobrowser.forms.form` would work but I'm not understanding how to properly utilize it, (if it is to be used at all as I wanted. e.g. Add the `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` hidden input fields to the form).

Is there something else I am missing or does RoboBrowser/Requests not support this type of post?
Is it that the form requires javascript to execute as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269064/submitting-a-post-request-to-an-aspx-page) with mechanize?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Solved

After much googling, re-posting for help on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2r021e/robobrowser_form_post/) and then randomly stumbling [this](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/issues/29) RoboBrowser issue that showed me how to properly use the 'fields.add_field()' method; the problem is solved.

e.g.

```
b_e_arg = robobrowser.forms.fields.Input('\<input name="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" \/\>')

b_e_target = robobrowser.forms.fields.Input('\<input name="__EVENTTARGET" value="PhoneListsControl$MasterDataControl$masterList$_ctl0$SelectButton" \/\>')

In [30]: form_find_b.add_field(b_e_target)
In [31]: form_find_b.add_field(b_e_arg)
```

Once the form was updated with these values, the form submit to "PhoneLists.aspx" works as expected.

```
In [33]: m.submit_form(form_find_b)

In [34]: m.url
Out[34]: u'http://example/PhoneLists.aspx'

In [35]: m.parsed.findAll('div', id='PhoneListsControl_phoneListMembersText')
Out[35]: [<div class="displayText" id="PhoneListsControl_phoneListMembersText">  Work  </div>]

In [36]: m.parsed.findAll('input', id='PhoneListsControl_phoneListDetail__ctl2_number')
Out[36]: [<input id="PhoneListsControl_phoneListDetail__ctl2_number" maxlength="50" name="PhoneListsControl:phoneListDetail:_ctl2:number" onkeyup="enableApplyButton('PhoneListsControl_')" type="text" value="95551234567"/>]
```

I hope anyone else that has to scrape ASPX sites finds this useful. Happy hacking to all!